# JQuery Multiple Images Auto Sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the images to increase when i expand the window, and when there’s space for another one, it will be plus one each line…

Suppose i open the HTML page with:

image1 image2 image3 
image4 image5 image6 
image5 image6 image7

if i expand the window, the images will increase and then i get 4 images (or more) per line:

image1 image2 image3 image4 
image5 image6 image7

and if i decrease, i will have the inverse action, like:

image1 image2
image3 image4
image5 image6 
image7

Something like this: http://pixelgrade.com/demos/lens/

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: I recommend looking into "responsive design."  There are several CSS and JavaScript frameworks (such as Bootstrap and Foundation ( http://foundation.zurb.com/ ) ) that may be useful.

Comment: Definitely look at Danko's answer, There is no need for JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give to this images some of those css properties

```
img {
  float:left;
  /*or*/
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Review this Demo **[Float](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm4L4/2/)** or  **[Inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm4L4/7/)**

For Responsive size you can use media queries but you need to know how many images you want to see at each browsers size. Like 1000px to 1200px 3 images per row and under 1000px only two images.

New Demo **[Responsive Size](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm4L4/20/)**

Comment: Yea, the images are right, but there is a problem, suppose i have a div width 350px and 3 images with width 100px each, i will have 50px with none, and the point is, i want the images to increase or decrease their size and auto adjust like they do with the css proprieties you gave me but without any space to fill.

This is the main ideia:
http://pixelgrade.com/demos/lens

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just dig into their CSS file ? It's not minified :) http://bit.ly/16v64Vo

From there you can find that we are using a grid system and based on resolution we alter the number of images per row.

Add to each image a class (eg. mosaic__item) and then assign them a different width using @media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
    .mosaic__item {
      width: 33.33333%; 
    } 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 901px) {
   .mosaic__item {
      width: 50%; 
   } 
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   .mosaic__item {
      width: 100%; 
   } 
}
```